# PHP PDO Bind or Execute

Tags: php, pdo

I have a simple question:

Which version is the correct one for preventing SQLi ?

```
$db_request = $db->prepare( "UPDATE users SET active = 0 WHERE id = ? AND active = ?" );

$db_request->execute( array( $uid, $hash ) );
```

or

```
using bindParam ?
```

Thanks for your time!

LE: ? = input from user

Comment: As long as you don't explain what is coming instead of the '?' chars in your SQL statement, it is impossible for us to know if injection is possible.

Comment: input from user

Comment: what do you mean by `preventing SQLi `???

Comment: Potaytoe, potahto.

Comment: Both will work the same as far as injection prevention goes. There might be some other differences, take a look at the suggested duplicate for more information.

Comment: with `bindParam()` , you can specify the data type in the third parameter.